# is this query a valid mongo jackson mapper query?

Tags: mongo-jackson-mapper

I'm trying to get a user by email or username from the database, imagine functionality that a user can login either with unique alias or email address, I thought the following would work but it doesn't,

```
User user  =  
coll.findOne(DBQuery.is("email", emailOrUsername).or(DBQuery.is("username", emailOrUsername)));
```

anything i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So apparently the way to create the above query is this:

```
coll.findOne(DBQuery.or(DBQuery.is("email", emailOrUsername),DBQuery.is("username",  emailOrUsername)));
```

I still don't know what the first query in the original question supposed to do.